# How to remove a XML tag from String using regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex, xml

I have a Java String which looks like

```
<ns3:PaymentDetail>
<ns3:CVCCode>000</ns3:CVCCode>
<ns3:CardNumber>0000000000</ns3:CardNumber>
<ns3:ExpirationMonth>00</ns3:ExpirationMonth>
<ns3:ExpirationYear>0000</ns3:ExpirationYear>
<ns3:PinNumber>00000</ns3:PinNumber>
</ns3:PaymentDetail>
```

I want to remove  tag content so that my String looks like

```
<ns3:PaymentDetail>

</ns3:PaymentDetail>
```

I want to use regular expression here. XML is long and these tags can be repeated more than once. There can be anything before PaymentDetails tag like ns1 or ns23, in brief, the size is not fixed.

Comment: I would recommend to parse it as xml, get all `PaymentDetail` nodes using xpath and remove all child nodes.

Comment: could you please mention  what is the desired output that you want?

Comment: I just have the string and have to store this in database.

Comment: I want the inner tags of paymentDetail to be removed.

Comment: @DattatraySatpute OP wants to remove everything insisde the PaymentDetail tag.

Comment: Is there anything outside the PaymentDetail tag that you need? Or you really just need all the PaymentDetail tags and nothing else?

Comment: @Philipp, There are other details outside payment details tag that I need. I just want to remove contents of payment details tag

Comment: Your code adds matches to a `List<String>`. Of course, if the desired result is a single string, this can’t provide the result in general. It’s not clear why you are following this approach at all. Either your task description or your code must be incomplete.

Comment: @Holger, I realized that now, my code is wrong I have edited that

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: So, the pattern and replacement string for a single `replaceAll` operation would do? E.g. `input.replaceAll("<(\\w+:PaymentDetail>)(?s).*?</\\1", "<$1</$1")`?

Comment: You should not use regex on xml since regex is not a regular language. You **will** run into problems at some point, e.g. when you have deep nested tags. You should look into a XML parser like jaxb instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I looked into it a bit and I think this MIGHT be what you are looking for:

```
Pattern patternPaymentDetailOpen = Pattern.compile("<[a-zA-Z0-9]*:PaymentDetail>");
Pattern patternPaymentDetailClose = Pattern.compile("</[a-zA-Z0-9]*:PaymentDetail>");
Matcher matcherPaymentDetail = patternPaymentDetailOpen.matcher(input);
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
int pos = 0;
while (matcherPaymentDetail.find()) {
    builder.append(input, pos, matcherPaymentDetail.end());
    matcherPaymentDetail.usePattern(patternPaymentDetailClose);
    if (matcherPaymentDetail.find()) {
        builder.append(input, matcherPaymentDetail.start(), matcherPaymentDetail.end());
        pos = matcherPaymentDetail.end();
    }
    matcherPaymentDetail.usePattern(patternPaymentDetailOpen);
}
builder.append(input, pos, input.length());
System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

It's just a quick and dirty code, you should test it and modify it to your needs. The idea is that we take everything before the first opening tag of payment details, then take the opening tag, then search for the closing tag and take it but ignore everything in between. This is repeated for all payment detail tags. After the last payment detail tag is closed, also take the rest of the string.

Example:

```
String input = "<parent><ns3:PaymentDetail>\n" +
                "<ns3:CVCCode>000</ns3:CVCCode>\n" +
                "<ns3:CardNumber>0000000000</ns3:CardNumber>\n" +
                "<ns3:ExpirationMonth>00</ns3:ExpirationMonth>\n" +
                "<ns3:ExpirationYear>0000</ns3:ExpirationYear>\n" +
                "<ns3:PinNumber>00000</ns3:PinNumber>\n" +
                "</ns3:PaymentDetail>"+
                "<another-tag> abc </another-tag>" +
                "<ns5:PaymentDetail>\n" +
                "<ns3:CVCCode>000</ns3:CVCCode>\n" +
                "<ns3:CardNumber>0000000000</ns3:CardNumber>\n" +
                "<ns3:ExpirationMonth>00</ns3:ExpirationMonth>\n" +
                "<ns3:ExpirationYear>0000</ns3:ExpirationYear>\n" +
                "<ns3:PinNumber>00000</ns3:PinNumber>\n" +
                "</ns5:PaymentDetail></parent>";
```

results in:

```
<parent><ns3:PaymentDetail></ns3:PaymentDetail><another-tag> abc </another-tag><ns5:PaymentDetail></ns5:PaymentDetail></parent>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply replaceAll

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String oldString = "<ns3:PaymentDetail><ns3:CVCCode>000</ns3:CVCCode><ns3:CardNumber>0000000000</ns3:CardNumber><ns3:ExpirationMonth>00</ns3:ExpirationMonth><ns3:ExpirationYear>0000</ns3:ExpirationYear><ns3:PinNumber>00000</ns3:PinNumber></ns3:PaymentDetail>";

    String newString = oldString.replaceAll("<ns3:PaymentDetail>[\\s\\S]*?</ns3:PaymentDetail>",
            "<ns3:PaymentDetail></ns3:PaymentDetail>");
    System.out.println(newString);
}
```

}

Comment: Bro ns3 dynamically generated. It is not hardcoded, i need some regex for that too